# using count(*) statement in microsoft access 2013

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

hi i have tried codes for using count(*) statement in microsoft access
i succeded by using this

```
SELECT Count(*) AS cafe3sales
FROM tblroder
WHERE OrderCode LIKE 'O03*';
```

But i need to show cafe 1 2 and 3 sales in one table. Can u help me ?
Thank you

This is my data in Excel:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with 1 , 2 , 3 order code?  only first 3?

Comment: You have a field `CafeID`, why are you not using that to select cafe 1,2 & 3?

Comment: i haven't know that can you please help me make the code thank you so much.

Comment: @MichaelLianto - When you say "...i need to show cafe 1 2 and 3 sales in one table." do you mean you want to add up sales from all three cafes (1 row showing the total) or you want to see totals for each cafe (3 rows)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Group by

```
SELECT Count(TableIDField) AS cafe3sales, Cafeid
FROM tblorder
Group By Cafeid
```

Comment: That will just count 1 for each and every order.

Comment: I had not seen data layout

Answer (score 0):

You could have access build the SQL for you in Query Design view by selecting Group by in the Total: row dropdown for the cafe column and count for the other column. If you then switch to SQLview you will see the sql code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to have the three results in one record

```
SELECT sum(iif(left(OrderCode,3)= 'O03',1,0)) AS cafe3sales,
       sum(iif(left(OrderCode,3)= 'O02',1,0)) AS cafe2sales,
       sum(iif(left(OrderCode,3)= 'O01',1,0)) AS cafe1sales,
FROM tblroder
```

Or this one to have in <strike>three</strike> diferent records. Will obtain three records only if you have at least one of each type (and no others exists).

```
SELECT count(*), left(OrderCode,3)
FROM tblroder
GROUP BY left(OrderCode,3)
ORDER BY left(OrderCode,3) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are unclear. When you say:

> ...i need to show cafe 1 2 and 3 sales in one table.

do you mean you want to know the number of sales (using `COUNT`) or the total value (using `SUM`)?

And do you want the value returned to be a total for all three cafes (1 row) or do you want to see totals for each cafe (3 rows)?

If you want one total for all three cafes use this to get the *number* of orders

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountOfOrders
FROM tblorder
WHERE CafeID IN ('C01', 'C02', 'C03')
```

or this to get the *value* of the orders

```
SELECT SUM(TotalPrice) AS SumOfTotalPrice
FROM tblorder
WHERE CafeID IN ('C01', 'C02', 'C03')
```

If you need these totals for each cafe you need to use `GROUP BY` & `HAVING`. Here are the same two queries as before but the result is split out for each cafe

```
SELECT CafeID, COUNT(*) AS CountOfOrders
FROM tblorder
GROUP BY CafeID
HAVING CafeID IN ('C01', 'C02', 'C03')

SELECT SUM(TotalPrice) AS SumOfTotalPrice
FROM tblorder
GROUP BY CafeID
HAVING CafeID IN ('C01', 'C02', 'C03')
```